# A Dark Theme for Windows 8

Tags: operating-systems, windows-8-preview, themes, visual-styles

Is there any way for me to use Windows 8 in a dark environment? For a long time I had headaches that I couldn't fid their cause. Now, I'm using a dark visual style for my Windows 7 and since then, I haven't have any problems. Now I want to use Windows 8 release preview but I cannot find any way to use it in a dark theme/visual style. I've seen the files needed are patched but couldn't find any visual style. I also searched for 3rd party apps, nothing.
I would very much appreciate if you could help me. Thanks.

Pictures below compare Explorer both in dark and Aero visual styles.

[image: Dark Visual Style]

[image: Aero]

Comment: How about dimming the monitor?

Comment: Not gonna help that much. I have it dimmed at max.

Comment: How about [This one](http://firefoxdude.deviantart.com/art/Windows-8-Dark-Metro-Theme-259191685)

Comment: Does the windows 7 patch work on 8?

Comment: @avrik That is for Win8's Metro (not desktop). Links are dead though :(

Comment: @SimonSheehan No, but a patch for Windows 8 is released. Take a look [here](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/32735-Windows-8-Consumer-Preview-x86-Theme-Patch)

Comment: You could conceivably do the same thing to the windows 8 explorer that you did to the windows 7 one, except that it wouldn't affect the main Metro interface (only the desktop view).  Keep in mind that you'd have to change the bootloader (OS select) theme too; it's almost a separate OS (in terms of complexity)!

Comment: I want to only change desktop, but how would I do that?

Comment: Have you tried the High Contrast themes in the Personalize settings? Particularly #1, #2 and black. However they change metro too (IMO, for the worse). But these are more for disability and physical reasons, not beauty. I guess you fit under the physical reasons category. It might get you by until a real theme comes out.

Comment: @RyanClarke No I don't have any phisycall condition. I just use my PC a lot. I use it for at least 10 hours a day. If you're using it too much, you might want to consider changing your OS too and after a few days, you'll see the difference. The thing with the HighContrast themes is that they remove all the beauty of the OS. I'm not THAT desparate.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori I wasn't calling you crippled. I had headaches a few years ago from a bad CRT monitor. So I know how it can be. I just didn't know how serious this was and if an ugly look was worth it. The metro interfaces really take a hit in high contrast theme.

Comment: No, not at all. I just thought you might think I had a seriuos condition. I think everybody who works a lot with computers, has this problem. Some just may don't know it. Anyway, I think by changing Windows colors and using some 3rd party apps, I might be able to work. Now I'm just looking for a Explorer replacement. I'll ask it here in another question though.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori I experienced the same problems after looking at a monitor for several hours a day. This software helps A LOT: http://stereopsis.com/flux/

Comment: How did you do it in Win7?

Comment: @PratyushNalam I modified a theme which is available [here](http://jaycee13.deviantart.com/art/Mango-XB-K-Visual-Style-7-244943275)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Themes for Windows 8** is a  free website dedicated to changing the appearance of your PC or Tablet with different visual styles, themes, skin packs etc.....

http://windows8themes.ms/

Alternatively I have found this dark theme for Windows 8 on **DeviantArt** entitled *Dark 8*:

[image]

Available from:
http://gr8stylex.deviantart.com/art/dark8-vs-for-windows-8-340960613

**Skin Pack** is another website to visually alter the appearance of your Windows 8, an example of a dark theme available called *Equinox Skin Pack*

[image]

Available from: http://www.skinpacks.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=89

This is just examples of two dark themes I found from those sites, but i'm sure a variety of others probably exist on them as well.

Comment: Your very welcome :)

Answer (score 11):

[Excerpt from my blog at http://anoori.me/](http://anoori.me/blog/general/the-dark-side-of-windows-8-(using-win8-in-dark))

Las week, I mentioned I tried to switch over to Windows 8, but I couldn’t do so because it was so bright for me. After a couple of days, I upgraded some parts of my PC and since I wanted to check out the UEFI booting speed of Windows 8, I figured I’d give it another shot.

After installation, I knew that I have to make my OS dark, so, after installing drivers and basic software, I set out to make my OS as dark as possible.

The "Advanced Color and Appearance Settings" dialog isn’t there, but there are programs that are using it, so I head over to the beloved regedit and changed it through Windows Registry. Here is the key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors]
```

[image]

I changed some colors, logged off and logged on again, started Microsoft Words and voila! It was dark. Good.

I started Photoshop and checked the best background for both dark and bright foreground texts. Turns out, it’s **[55,55,57]** in RGB format. Here’s the photo I’ve created:

[image]

As you can see, it tests the background against all kinds of foreground. I changed my all keys in the regedit and in case you’re interested, [here's a copy for you to download](https://app.box.com/s/c084ae7d6f7c8cf43fd0). Just double click on it and restart your windows. (It works on Windows 7 too).

This made most of my OS dark, after that I set my Aero color to black and changed all the font size settings in

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display
```

to 11, clicked **Apply** to get a bigger font my OS.

I changed my Office theme to "Black", my Visual Studio to "Dark" theme, the Notepad++ to "Obsidian", etc.

[image]

The only remaining part was my Windows Explorer. I couldn’t change it without a Visual Style so for now, I’ve customized the [NexusFile](http://www.xiles.net/nexusfile/) and using it as my primary file manager. It’s simple, has a black theme, it’s customizable and **it has tabs**. Here is a screenshot of it.

[image]

In addition to all these changes, I use [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) for a while now. It changes your monitor's light depending on time of day. It's so awesome. I strongly recommend it. It is free and also available for Mac/Linux and iOS.

I'm using my Windows 8 for a week now. I just have some minor issues with it but in general I LOVE IT, more than Windows 7. It’s blazing fast. You should definitely try it.

[Source](http://www.alireza-noori.com/general/the-dark-side-of-windows-8-using-win8-in-dark/)

Comment: @AzulShiva trusted who? Me? You can download the `.reg` file and see the contents of it before applying. It won't change your Windows in any way that it's unusable. Not sure what you're implying. I just backed up a couple of keys using regedit itself.