# Restoring default color scheme on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, colors, themes, regedit

When I was trying to find some color scheme comfortable for eyes on my Windows 8, I have changed my regedit settings using `*.reg` file. Unfortunately, I don't like it anymore and I would like to restore the default Windows 8 color scheme. How to do it in the easiest way?

Originally, I followed the instructions given here: [A Dark Theme for Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/431844/a-dark-theme-for-windows-8)

Comment: Right click on desktop, the customize (prispôsobiť ;) ) and then select what theme you want... I guess.

Comment: Oh man, I'm so stupid!! This was so easy. I should better delete this question to not to be ashamed :-)

Comment: Actually, I couldn't change window background easily (or find proper theme) to have a dark one, so I tried to do so using regedit and I couldn't restore it in regedit. In the end it was so easy it didn't came to my mind...

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on desktop, the click "customize" and select what you want.